# How to display query without executing it with eloquent

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I want to display a query without executing it using Eloquent. I want to write something like:

```
\DB::table('my_table')-> updateOrInsert(['a' => 'b'], ['c' => 'd']);
```

It's a production action so I am a bit stressed about running it directly. Is there any way to display it instead of running it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a query builder instance you can use `toSql()`. Since the `updateOrInsert()` method does not return an builder instance you can't prevent its execution that way. Instead you can put the query inside a `DB::pretend()` closure and it should return the query it would execute.

```
\DB::pretend(function() {
    \DB::table('my_table')->update(['a' => 'b']);
});
```

Should return:

```
[
    [
        "query" => "update `my_table` set `a` = ?",
        "bindings" => [
            "b",
        ],
        "time" => 0.01,
    ],
]
```

Note: the example you provided will never work because `insertOrUpdate()` does not exist. I believe you're looking for `updateOrInsert()`

Answer (score 0):

You can see raw queries with:

```
$foo = DB::getQueryLog();
var_dump($foo);
```

It will execute the queries.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. A good tutorial is available here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

Comment: @Gab It is possible. See my answer.